# GAE (JPA) add database entry manually

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new to the GAE, and want to add some sample records to the database manually. For example, in Android I can do sqlite3 somedb.db and the simply insert, update, delete, etc. But how to do it in GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do manual data entry from GAE admin panel....
once you log-in, select option datastore viewer and then click on 'Create' tab, select the table name, click next and start inserting your values